# Shutdown a linux computer depending on the battery level

Tags: linux, script, battery, shell-script, bash-scripting

Is there a way to shutdown a linux-based computer when the battery charge drops below a certain level? I have searched through the shutdown and poweroff manuals but found nothing relevant.

Comment: There must be a way, because that's what the Battery Monitor does on my Linux laptop.

Comment: I believe this is commonly done already in many distributions. Which one are you using?

Comment: @atsag Knowing your distro and desktop environment would be very useful here.

Comment: Thank you everyone for taking the time! I am using Linux Mint 17.3, but if there would be a more general solution - one covering more unices - that would be preferable.

Comment: Google is your friend - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84437/how-do-i-make-my-laptop-sleep-when-it-reaches-some-low-battery-threshold   and https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=162900

Comment: @davidgo: Thank you a lot  for taking the time! I found the second link yesterday, and worked on it to create my proposed answer, but the first one is also great, so I'll update my answer, mentioning your comment as further reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right!
I did some more thorough research on the topic, and it appears that this can be done with a script. The source of inspiration for my script below, is the following topic in the arch linux forums:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=162900 ,and more specifically the first post by vacant.

```
#!/bin/bash
BATTINFO=`acpi -b`
CRITICAL_PERCENTAGE=21
FILE_LOCATION="/home/username/LOW_BATTERY" #change this to correct username!

if [[ `echo $BATTINFO | grep Discharging` && `echo $BATTINFO | cut -c 25-26 ` -lt $CRITICAL_PERCENTAGE ]]
then
echo `date` >> $FILE_LOCATION 
echo "Was forced to hibernate, due to low battery status">>$FILE_LOCATION       
echo $BATTINFO >> $FILE_LOCATION
sudo pm-hibernate 
fi
```

The job can be automated using a cron job, by editing the root user's crontab file (e.g using su in a terminal, and then crontab -e), for the script to be executed once in every regular interval (e.g 2 minutes).
As mentioned by davidgo above, there is a (very) similar question answered in http://unix.stackexchange.com, that could be used as a reference for a more advanced approaching.